# Migrating to prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, statements

Basically I'm converting all my statements in my class file to prepared statements. After reading over the php.net manual, I still cannot see where or what my error is.

In this particular function I am getting the profile of a user by the users ID.

Any help fellas?

I was able to answer my own question. Using `SELECT *` doesn't work very well with object oriented prepared statements.

Rather, select all the fields in the table needed and then bind them accordingly.

This particular function is getting all the details of a user by their ID.

Enjoy.

```
    public function getProfile($id){
  if($result = $this->link->prepare("SELECT id,first,last,full_name,email,photo FROM dl_users WHERE id=?")){
   $result->bind_param('i',$id);
   $result->execute();
   $result->store_result();
   $result->bind_result($id,$first,$last,$full_name,$email,$bio,$hometown,$position,$skills,$photo);
   if($result->num_rows == 1){
    $user = array();
    $result->fetch();
    $user['id'] = $id;
    $user['first'] = $first;
    $user['last'] = $last;
    $user['full_name'] = $full_name;
    $user['email'] = $email;
    $user['photo'] = $photo;
    return $user;
   }
   $result->close();
  }
   }
```

Comment: And the error is...? I don't see you returning `$id` anywhere, and since it's not a reference parameter, whatever you fetch into it will be gone when the function returns.

Comment: id is int you should use `i` in the placeholder `bind_param("i", $id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQLi's prepared statements work with variable references.  `$result->fetch()` doesn't return the fields, it returns a boolean.

What you are can do is this:

```
public function getProfile($id){
    if($result = $this->link->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =?")){
        $result->bind_param("s", $id);
        $result->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            return $row;
        }else{
            return array("error"=>"Profile-Not-Found");
        }
        $result->close();
    }
}
```

Note: This requires mysqlnd be installed.

Comment: Basically I'm converting my old sql statements from:

`public function getProfile($id){
  if($result = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ".$id)){
   if($result->num_rows != 0){
    return $result->fetch_assoc();
   }else{
    return array("error"=>"Profile-Not-Found");
   }
  }
 }`

Your adjustments to my prepared statement do not work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me.  Give me a sec to update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your id field is an integer, you must bind the param in this way:

```
$result->bind_param("i", $id);
```

More info here: `http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php`

Comment: This shouldn't matter too much.  MySQL will convert types.  Both `id =  1` and `id = '1'` will work.

Comment: Not always. It depends on the mode configured in the server.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to answer my own question. Using `SELECT *` doesn't work very well with object oriented prepared statements.

Rather, select all the fields in the table needed and then bind them accordingly.

This particular function is getting all the details of a user by their ID.

Enjoy.

```
public function getProfile($id){
  if($result = $this->link->prepare("SELECT id,first,last,full_name,email,photo FROM dl_users WHERE id=?")){
   $result->bind_param('i',$id);
   $result->execute();
   $result->store_result();
   $result->bind_result($id,$first,$last,$full_name,$email,$bio,$hometown,$position,$skills,$photo);
   if($result->num_rows == 1){
    $user = array();
    $result->fetch();
    $user['id'] = $id;
    $user['first'] = $first;
    $user['last'] = $last;
    $user['full_name'] = $full_name;
    $user['email'] = $email;
    $user['photo'] = $photo;
    return $user;
   }
   $result->close();

  }
 }
```

Comment: Yes but you'd have to know or expect what you're receiving from the database. You can't just loop through it like before.